# Как получить состояние с линейного датчика Rpi.GPIO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

Есть сборка из Rpi 4 и 2-х датчиков, которые определяют черную линию(если датчик над черной линией, то выдаёт 0, иначе подаёт сигнал 1). Не могу найти информацию по получению состояния этого датчика. То есть, мне надо посмотреть что выдаёт каждый из датчиков. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример из вики амперки

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN)
 
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    button = GPIO.input(2)
    print(button)
```

Пояснение: `GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN)` - назначаем второй пин на вход, `button = GPIO.input(2)` - пишем значение в переменную.

**!** *Обратите внимание, фактические номера ножек не соответсnвуют номерам GPIO, т.е. перед написанием программы загуглите распиновку, чтобы не было ошибок*

Только в данном случае объявлен один вход. Соответственно вы назначаете столько сколько вам нужно и пишете значения ваших датчиков куда вам удобно.

Comment: Спасибо большое)